# Image Share on Facebook using Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I am following [Custom Story in Android](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/open-graph) tutorial. I want to shared image only  when u select image from gallery. But i am getting error **Null Pointer Exception**. Have there any suggestions that how can i solve this.
Thank you.

My Image Sharing code. [Here](http://pastie.org/8744460)

My Error. [Error](http://pastie.org/8744476)

Comment: would u please upload logcat same as ur code on other link???

Comment: it is nt readable... copy the logcat and paste... it is simpl

Answer (score 1):

you need to convert it to byte array and then in your Bundle you need to pass that ByteArray like this

```
Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
Bitmap bmp = "your bitmap";
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
postParams.putByteArray("images", bytearray);
```

at last you need to set this

```
Request request = new Request(session, "me/photos", postParams,
                    HttpMethod.POST, callback);
```

Comment: same error. 02-18 12:59:25.447: E/AndroidRuntime(13233): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {web.revolution.loginlogoutfb/web.revolution.loginlogoutfb.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException